# Who does this Urdu proverb originate from?

Tags: quote-source, hindi-language, urdu-language

First let me try my best to transliterate the Urdu version of the quote in question:

> Insaan ho, to kisi ke kaam ao; warna khao, pio aur chale jao.

A rough translation would be something like:

> If you are human, be of some help to someone. Otherwise eat, drink and leave (this earth; as in "die").

I have tried to google both the transliteration and the english version but it doesn't come up anywhere. I only know it via oral tradition from someone in my family.

Comment: Not that I could answer this question, but it would be neat if you included the non-transliterated Urdu as well. Thanks!

Comment: @cmw Thank you for your comment. However, neither can I write (or read, for that matter) actual Urdu, nor do I have in any way access to the original, written Urdu version. My apologies!

Comment: Ah, too bad! Maybe someone will else will be able to contribute it.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually from Altaf Hussain Hali, here is the [link](https://www.rekhta.org/nazms/hubb-e-vatan-altaf-hussain-hali-nazms) to transliteration at rekhta.

The original is:

*mard ho tum kisī ke kaam aao

varna khaao piyo chale jaao*

You can search on the page for "mard" to find it.

Comment: देर आए, दुरुस्त आए / *der aa_e, durust aa_e*, as we say in Hindustani. Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange!